# Checkbox on Sql Server Reporting Services Report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I'm working on a report in SSRS 2005 that is a questionnaire with yes/no answers.  Trying to get a checkbox on the report.  Have tried using windings for the font and an iif statement to set the character, but that doesn't come out correctly when exporting to PDF.  I'm using local reports, not from a report server.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest/simplest solution is just to use an embedded image with a expression which sets the source of the image to the checked or not checked version. This will work across export types (except text/csv).

I am assuming however you want this to be non-interactive.

Answer (score 0):

I'm about to venture down this path, as well (clients that require printed forms look exactly as they always have, basically).  Did you try this suggestion?

Keith, aside from the image solution, what are the options?